Proving $x/x=1+0x/x$ in a wheel.
According to Approach0, this is new to MSE.
Here $\color{red}{{\rm red}}$ indicates an error found after the fact.
The Question:

Let $W$ be a wheel. Show that $$x/x=1+0x/x$$ for all $x\in W$.

Motivation:
Much like my recent question, I saw the identity on Wikipedia and thought I'd try to prove it, seeing as though I'd like to learn more about wheel theory.
The Definition:
A wheel is an algebraic structure $(W,0,1,+,\cdot, /)$ where:

$W$ is a set,
$0,1\in W,$
$+$ and $\cdot$ are binary operations,
$/$ is a unary operation,

and

$+,\cdot$ are associative, commutative, and with identities $0$ and $1$, respectively,
$//x=x$,
$/(xy)=/x/y$,
$xz+yz=(x+y)z+0z$,
$(x+yz)/y=x/y+z+0y$,
$0\cdot 0=0$,
$(x+0y)z=xz+0y$,
$/(x+0y)=/x+0y$,
$0/0+x=0/0$.

We denote $0/0$ by $\bot$.
The final axiom can be written as
$$\bot+x=\bot.$$
Thoughts:
I'm guessing this is easy; however, I don't see it yet.
The most relevant axiom appears to be
$$(x+yz)/y=x/y+z+0y.$$
If I set $y=x/x$ and $z=1$, I get
$$(x+x/x)/\color{red}1=x/x+1+0(x/x).$$
That's close.
Do they intend $(0x)/x$ or $0(x/x)$? Are they equivalent? If so, how do I prove it?
Well, to answer this sub-question, consider
$$(0x)/x=(0+0x)/x=0/x+ (0x/x).$$
This is also close.
Second Attempt:
Using $/(x+0y)=/x+0y$,
$$\begin{align}
x/x&=x/(x+0)\\
&=x/(x+0\cdot 0)\\
&\color{red}{=x/x+x0\cdot0}\tag{?}\\
&=x/x+0x\\
&=(/x+0)x.
\end{align}$$
But what next? This attempt is inspired by a standard proof in ring theory, where $0_rx_r=0_r$ is shown for $0_r$ the additive identity and $x_r$ an element of the ring.
I know that $0x\neq 0$ in general.
Lemma:
I could use
$$/x=/(x1)=/x/1.$$

$(0x)/x = 0(x/x)$ - isn't this just associativity of $\cdot$?

Well spotted, @mihaild. Thank you!

Getting used to these axioms is tough!

(I personally find $x^{*}$ to be easier to read and work with than $/x$, so I'm going to use $*$ to denote the involution.  Also I'm freely using commutativity, associativity, and $0$ and $1$ as the additive and multiplicative identities.)
Start with the axiom $(x + yz)y^* = xy^* + z + 0y$.  Setting $x=0$ gives $$(0+yz)y^*=0y^*+z+0y \implies yy^*z = 0y + 0y^* + z.$$  Now set $z=1$, giving $$yy^*1=0y + 0y^* + 1 \implies yy^*=0y+0y^*+1.$$  In your previous question you showed that $0y+0y^*=0yy^*$.  So conclude that $$yy^*=1+0yy^*,$$ which is what you wanted to prove.

Note also that not setting $z=1$, but still using the previous (non-axiomatic) result that $0y+0y^=0yy^$, gives this more general result (where the specialization to $z=1$ is obvious): $z yy^{} = z + 0 yy^{}$.
